# Is it possible to insert the record using multi dimension array?

Tags: php

The scenario is

I would like to insert an record like this:

Firstly, i have an array of what datafield i need to insert

```
 $field = Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Name )
```

Secondly, I have an array of mail

```
$mail = Array ( [0] => a@a.com [1] => foodil@g.com )
```

Lastly, I have an multi dimension array that has Name,

```
$set = Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => leo [4] => NULL ) )
```

**however, It can be  more than one field, 
eg. it can be also have a field of phone (and also address, geneder...whatever) , then it will be:**

```
   $field = Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Name  [2] => Phone ) 

   $set = Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => leo [4] => NULL )  [5] => Array ( [1] => 4343343 [4] => 3453343 ))
```

The problem is , how to insert in the scenario like this? :
The query should look like this

```
$query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,Name,Phone) VALUES ($mail[] , $set[][], $set[][])";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you not simply insert a single record for each subscriber?, if the fields on the databases are NOT-NULL you can insert default values instead. however, i would use json_encode() instead serialized(), this will maintain the data readble for others languages using a json parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() and unserialize (its opposite) to store multidimensional arrays into mysql